# Why are pendulums' time periods amplitude-invariant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time

Whether the angle is low or high, it returns at the same time.

How come this is true?

Comment: The period is only independent of the amplitude for small amplitudes (i.e. small angles).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero prove it.

Comment: See Eq.(24.C.59) of this document: http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/chapter24.pdf and all the discussion therein.

Comment: Hi Jossie. The fact the period doesn't depend on the amplitude follows from solving the equation of motion (for small amplitudes). Are you asking about this solution is done, or are you asking for an intuitive feel as to how and why this happens?

Comment: As quick search on wikipedia shows that your assertion is false: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

This does happen.

Before answering let me put some interesting links

https://youtu.be/4a0FbQdH3dY - For Love for physics

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum

You can easily find mathematical solutions that proov this fact.

Let me try to explain it qualitatively, or in a more physics sense rather than mathematics.

- this is the case of simple harmonic motion. Let's make some assumptions - the string is massless, the ball can be represented by a point mass and the motion is confined to small angles (just to make sure that recovering force is proportional to angle or the distance moved from the mean position - which is a necessary condition for SHM).
- Now, what happens when the amplitude is larger? Since force is directly proportional to displacement from mean position, there is a greater force that is pulling the bob towards mean position and hence greater acceleration.
- Also, because the amplitude is larger, the displacement is more. This happens in such a way that the time required for completing the cycle remains constant that is independent of the amplitude.
- a slightly different viewpoint - when amplitude is larger, the bob has to travel more distance. But at the same time, it travels at a greater average speed (note: average velocity will be 0 over the cycle).
- From this basic analysis we can conclude that the bob has a greater speed as well as it needs to travel greater distance if the amplitude increases.
- time needed to travel is distance divided by speed.

For exact solution we have to depend on the mathematics that explains the dynamics of this system.

Note that in this system all quantities, acceleration, velocity, as well as displacement are variable, thus it is bit harder to arrive at this conclusion based on pure qualitative analysis.

Comment: Confined to small angles? What's the boundary?

Comment: Actually for small angles we approximate sine(angle) to angle in radians. So, the angle should be small enough to satify this approximation. The exact value will delen on the level of accuracy and precision you are looking at.